# How can rails gems Apartment and Datagrid work together nicely?

Tags: ruby-on-rails, datagrid, multi-tenant

[Apartment](https://github.com/influitive/apartment) is being implemented into a large project that uses [Datagrid](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid). Apartment is configured to switch Postgresql schemas (tenants) on a per subdomain basis.
The problem is that the [Filters](https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid/wiki/Filters), which should reference their tenant specific schema, pull data out of the public schema.

Is there a way to get datagrid filters to look at the correct schema in postgresql?

Answer (score 0):

I opened an issue on the Datagrid github account and got an answer from bogdan:

> "Seems, you need to wrap select with proc like this:
>
> ```
> :select => proc {  User.order(:last_name).all.map{ |u| [u.full_name, u.id] }
> ```
>
> In this way datagrid will query select options every time filter is
>   rendered. :select without proc can only be used when options are
>   constant."

https://github.com/bogdan/datagrid/issues/70#issuecomment-23002811

Hard to say why it worked locally without the proc, but this is the answer.